# Nhibernate Delete Child of Parent Model - MVC3

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, repository-pattern

I have a page which displays the model details(in this case Franchise), but also displays a tabular list of notes about the franchise. What is the best way to delete one of the notes?

Currently i have a franchiseRepository which takes care of all the crud operations for the franchise Model. Would i be best to create a note repository also to add crud functionality? Or is there an easier way around it, like implementing it within the franchiseRepository(or would that be breaking some ddd rules like srp)?

```
public class Parent()
{
    public string name{get; set;}
    public IList<Note> notes{get;set;}
    //And so on
}
public class Note()
{
    public string content{get; set;}
    //And so on
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent should have a method like RemoveNote() which will remove the note from the list.
use cascade = all-delete-orphan on the on to manny relation and inverse = true on mapping. And you should not have Note repository.

```
    public virtual void RemoveNote(Note note)
    {
        if (_notes.Contains(note))
        {
            _notes.Remove(note);
            note.Parent = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok so in removeNote() i first load all the notes for the parent, then recursively look through the list till i find the note i want to delete, then SaveOrUpdate(Model)? Does that sound about right?

Comment: @Shuhel Ahmed - Ok cool - i will stick a method like that on my domain class - do you think this is the right place to put it?

Comment: @geepie yes it should be in your parent class as this is aggregate root.

Comment: @Shuhel Ahmed can you point me to enabling cascade = all-delete-orphan when configuring fluent nhibernate with automapping?

Comment: @geepie sorry i never used fluent nhibernate.